# How do I prevent the texture from stretching in Three JS

Tags: three.js, 3d

Im new in THREE JS and Ive tried most of the solutions I have found but it doesnt seem to work. Right now this is what Im using:

```
var canvasTexture = new THREE.CanvasTexture(cnvs);
canvasTexture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
canvasTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
canvasTexture.flipY = false;
canvasTexture.anisotropy = 16;
```

And this is the result, it still somehow stretched making it a bit blurry.

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHDeJ.png)

also here is the canvas where I use fabric js.
[fabric js canvas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlDGW.png)

is there a way to fix this?